What movie has divorced wives safari-chasing ex husbands in the forest?
I watched a movie in 1989 where women somewhere in a hot region of america have formed a tribe in a forest somewhere. They are divorced or mistreated women, and they lure men into wilderness and then chase them and kill them on safari. The scenery was similar to the rocky mountains.
There may be similar films, it has a scene where the woman is wrestling with a man in some forest, and she is trapped, so she takes off an earring and pokes him in they eye, at which point he is vanquished and she kills him. 
I watched it on holiday with a friend on TV when i was 12, i always wanted to know the name of the film. 

I think you're after the obscure Lethal Woman (AKA The Most Dangerous Woman Alive) from 1988 with Merete Van Kamp and Shannon Tweed.

A group of men are told that they have won an "erotic vacation" at a fantasy island. In reality, they are being lured to the island by women they have wronged, and once there they are captured and set loose on the island to be hunted down.

You can see a man's eyes pierced with earrings in this review (Careful: Contains A Nude Image!) And here's the trailer:



